# Lumen - remove duplicate method

Tags: php, laravel, lumen

In Lumen I have duplicated method 'respondError()' in the base `Controller.php` class and `Handler.php` in the Exception folder.

To avoid duplication, where do you suggest to move this method to so it will be easily accessible to any classes?

```
public function respondError($errorType = '', $message = null, $statusCode = 500)
{
    return response([
        'success'    => false,
        'error_type' => $errorType,
        'errors'     => [],
        'message'    => $message,
    ], $statusCode);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should move the code to its own class:

```
class ErrorResponse {
    protected $errorType = null; 
    protected $message = null; 
    protected $statusCode = null; 

    public __construct($errorType = '', $message = null, $statusCode = 500) {
        $this->errorType = $errorType; 
        $this->message = $message;
        $this->statusCode = statusCode ; 
    } 

    public getResponse() {
        return response([
            'success'    => false,
            'error_type' => $this->errorType,
            'errors'     => [],
            'message'    => $this->message,
        ], $this->statusCode);
    }
}
```

Why should you add the overhead you will ask? You may find in the future, that you want to add details to the Response, e.g. a debugging traceback of an exception, etc. or you might want to return the response from a function: The typical situation: Your controller calls an API function, the API function gives some low level error, but the controller needs to add details to it. Using the framework error class for this, will make your whole API dependent on the framework, which you should avoid as best as you can.

You can use the code now from everywhere:

```
 $error = new ErrorResponse('bad error', 'something went wrong!');
 return $error->getResponse();
```

Answer (score 0):

it depends on what pattern you are writing, if you use base mvc, it is better to create a controller that inherits from the base controller and the rest from him and writing in it your code. If you use the repository and service it is better to write there in the basic service.